# we are not receiving callbacks when events happen via Event Notification System

Tags: event-notification-service

**Solved:** found out we were actually receiving the callbacks! Our Apigee proxy was conflicting with the JSON payload but we were able to acknowledge salesforce is configured correctly! Thanks guys

I am running into an issue with how salesforce is suppose to work. They have a feature where we can receive callbacks when events happen via Event Notification System. We have done all the prework needed to setup this system but are not receiving callbacks to the endpoint URL we have configured via REST. Do you have information as to why this might be? My only thoughts are somehow this is not a feature available with this account but it seems as this is should be because I am able to send transactional emails and have setup the Callback and verified it.

Things we have done already to setup:

We have registered a callback URL and verified the URL. Salesforce did send the payload to our app proving salesforce can talk to our app. We setup a subscription with event categories that we want to listen on. Also our app is ready to receive payloads but we are not receiving anything after sending a transactional email.
here's the steps I used showing json body

step 1: create call back and then verify it URL:
/platform/v1/ens-callbacks

```
[
    {
        "callbackName": "cb2",
        "url": "https://example.com/my-call-back-endpoint",
        "maxBatchSize": 1000
    }
]
```

step 2: create subscription with callback id URL:
/platform/v1/ens-subscriptions

```
[{
  "callbackId": "006fc71f-e256-47ad-bd61-91eacf5ec99",
  "subscriptionName": "sub1",
  "eventCategoryTypes":["TransactionalSendEvents.EmailSent","TransactionalSendEvents.EmailNotSent", "TransactionalSendEvents.EmailBounced"],
  "filters": []
}]
```

step 3: create transactional send definition, Note this fails at first creation and I have to run a patch to set status to "Active" The failure says: "The creation of the Transactional Journey failed" URL:
/messaging/v1/email/definitions

```
{
    "definitionKey": "EXAMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME_TM",
    "status": "Active",
    "name": "EXAMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME_TM",
    "description": "Simple Email",
    "classification": "Default Transactional",
    "content": {
        "customerKey": "fff3f9e7-5c2f-41d7-931d-1761979577ae"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "list": "AQB"
    },
    "options": {
        "trackLinks": true,
        "bcc": [
            "%%blindCopyAddress%%"
        ],
        "cc": [
            "%%copyAddress%%"
        ],
        "createJourney": true
    }
}
```

Step 4: Run Patch URL:
/messaging/v1/email/definitions/EXAMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME_TM

```
{
  "status": "Active"
}
```

step 5: trigger transactional message send URL:
/messaging/v1/email/messages

```
{
    "definitionKey": "EXAMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME_TM",
    "recipients": [
        {
            "contactKey": "my_email_address_here",
            "to": "my_email_address_here",
            "attributes": {

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you've performed all the right steps but (as always) the devil is in the details. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to recreate your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out! Let me know what you think. I have added the code I am running.

Comment: found out we were actually receiving the callbacks! Our Apigee proxy was conflicting with the JSON payload but we were able to acknowledge salesforce is configured correctly! Thanks guys